# Excel VBA - Loop through worksheets, copy cells, reference into first worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a planning workbook where my company would have individual sheets (all set the same way) planning individual projects. These sheets would have certain cells (the same on each sheet) that would then be referenced by the main master schedule, a compilation of the high points of the subproject schedules. Is this possible? I am quite new at VBA coding so please be nice :)

I currently have a bit of code written to copy and paste into the last empty cell in Column B on the target sheet, but this code doesn't work anyway (havent figured out why yet). But ideally I would like the cells to be referenced, not copy+pasted, to avoid miscommunication between sheets when things change. Code pasted below for reference, would also appreciate help fixing this in addition to the other referencing issue.

```
Sub LoopAndInsert()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
    Set target = Worksheets("Global Schedule Gantt") 'sheet we're copying to
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  'loop through all worksheets
    
     If ws.Name <> target.Name Then   'if not the target sheet then...
         'copy range into the next blank row in column C
         ws.Range("CopyToGlobal").Copy target.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     End If
     
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `CopyToGlobal`? A named range or? If so how do you have it work on multiple sheets?

Comment: Yes that is a named range. Right now I only have it working on one sheet because I haven't attempted using multiple if I can't get a single sheet to work! I don't know a ton about named ranges as it is so please forgive me if that's incorrect as well

Comment: If you put this `MsgBox ws.Range("CopyToGlobal").Address` into the `If statement`, what is the result? What is not working i.e. what is the error (number, description)?

Comment: Is it a fixed range that you are using or is it supposed to change on each sheet? You can add this into your question about the ranges or how it's supposed to find the ranges on each sheet and that can easily be worked into VBA.

Comment: It is a fixed range on each sheet. Each sheet (aside from the first/master sheet) is created off the same template. The range from each sheet I wish to have referenced on the main sheet is the same range.

Comment: So it's column B from what row down to last row? Or a specific row? And am I correct in guessing that you want a formula to go in the master sheet like `=Sheet1!$A$1` referencing the other sheets rather than the cell value itself?

Comment: Yes correct on the reference not the cell value. Each Range of cells from the sub worksheets is 7 columns x 15 rows. Beginning in cell B8 on the master I would like to paste the cell references, and then for the next worksheet, it would locate that first empty cell in column B below the previously pasted references, and paste the next range, and so on.

Comment: So the range on each of the sub worksheets is `B8:H23`? Then on the master is this all getting put into column B only or is it also columns `B:H`?

Comment: No, and this is why I was attempting to use a named range albeit incorrectly, because the range from each sub worksheet is C14:I16, C18:I18, C23:I23, C25:I26, C29:I29, C31:I33, C35:I36, C41:I42. And ideally would want it referenced into columns B:H with no blank rows.

Comment: OK so the whole range on every sub sheet is `C14:I42`? Are all the gaps between the sections you want are they blank? (EG is `C17:I17` and C19:I22` etc all blank? If so we can loop through all the cells in that range and test if the cell is blank or not. If it's not blank then it goes to the relevant column in the master and on the next available row?

Comment: They are not blank. They are just more subcategories of planning that don't need to be seen in the master sheet.

Comment: @Gilly see if my new answer is right. It loops through rows 14:42 on the sub sheets and checks that it's one of the rows you listed above. then loops through the columns and puts them into the master.

Comment: @Gilly Hi Gilly did your problem get solved or not?

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're after. I'm assuming you want the cells in the master sheet to simply reference (eg `=Sheet1!$A$1`) rather than just have the value.

EDIT: Changed code upon new information.

```
Sub LoopAndInsert()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'I would set these 2 off with this.
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim ws As Worksheet, target As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long, lrowMaster As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Set target = Worksheets("Global Schedule Gantt") 'sheet we're copying to
lrowMaster = target.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  'loop through all worksheets
    If ws.Name <> target.Name Then   'if not the target sheet then...
        For i = 14 To 42
            Select Case i
                Case 14, 15, 16, 18, 23, 25, 26, 29, 31, 32, 33, 35, 36, 41, 42
                lrowMaster = lrowMaster + 1 'Move down to next available row
                For j = 3 To 9
                    target.Cells(lrowMaster, j - 1).Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!" & ws.Cells(i, j).Address
                Next j
            End Select
        Next i
    End If
Next ws

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

### Copy Cell References of a Non-Contiguous (Multi-Area) Range

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopAndInsert()
    
    Const dstName As String = "Global Schedule Gantt"
    Const dstCol As String = "B"
    Const srcRange As String = "CopyToGlobal"
    ' Or:
    'Const srcRange as String _
        = "C14:I16,C18:I18,C23:I23,C25:I26,C29:I29,C31:I33,C35:I36,C41:I42"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim cel As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName)
        Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dstCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim sRng As Range
    Dim dRng As Range
    For Each src In wb.Worksheets
        If src.Name <> dstName Then
            For Each sRng In src.Range(srcRange).Areas
                Set dRng = cel.Resize(sRng.Rows.Count, sRng.Columns.Count)
                    dRng.Formula _
                        = "='" & src.Name & "'!" & sRng.Cells(1).Address(0, 0)
                Set cel = cel.Offset(sRng.Rows.Count)
            Next sRng
        End If
    Next src

End Sub
```